# CSS how to align group of elements horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble aligning a paragraph element with a group of button elements. I'm using jQuery and CSS to try and do this.

Here is what I see:

[image]

And ideally I would like them all to be on the same horizontal line at the top of the screen, to avoid wasting pixel real-estate as I am. So have the DesignName text then immediately to the right of it in a line have the buttons.

Here is how the elements are being added in code:

```
var theDiv = $("#theDiv");

theDiv.append('<div id="buttonMenuDiv"></div>');

var buttonDiv = $("#buttonMenuDiv");
buttonDiv.append('<p id="DesignName" class="DesignName">DesignName</p>');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="MainMenu" value="Main Menu" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="NewModule" value="New Module" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="SearchDesigns" value="Search Designs" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="DesignDescription" value="Design Description" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="SaveWork" value="Save Work" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="PackageDesign" value="Package Design" >');
buttonDiv.append('<input type="button" id="Tutorial" value="Tutorial" >');
```

The "DesignName" class just specifies font attributes (size, color) so I didn't include it. Thanks for any help.

(Having some EDITING trouble with the single quotes in the append() calls)

Comment: You're using jquery to append the elements...why?

Comment: Use float and make to specify the width....

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/v5eYt/1/

Comment: I probably would just use HTML markup for the buttons, then style and align with CSS. I don't see why this is done in jquery

Comment: @aquinas I don't see the difference. Either way I'm dealing with DOM objects right? But I'm not attached to this particular way, whatever works at the end of the day.

Comment: Is there some reason you're using a `<p>` element? If you want it to be inline with the rest, why not use an element better suited for inline display, like a `<span>`.

Comment: @graystateiscoming Excellent, wow! I didn't know about that one and it really helped with my test element.

Comment: Glad it helped. Different elements have different default display properties. `p` is for "paragraph", which is a block style element. Better to use the proper element instead of restyling an element that is being used outside its intended purpose.

Comment: Or, don't use jquery at all: http://jsfiddle.net/bpNnr/

Comment: put all this in a div and use "float:left" that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#theDiv * {
display:inline;
}
```

Just make the elements inline instead of block.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5eYt/3/

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph's and div's are of [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) type, which means they are automatically followed by a line break. Input's are not, and if you want "Design Name" to not be followed by break, you should probably just put it in a span (span's are considered inline elements, which join the flow of text around them).   Floating as mentioned in the above comments will also work, but it comes with a bit more baggage - if you're just trying to keep a bunch of simple items on the same line, inline elements (or setting "display: inline" in the css).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a css rule for those buttons to implement this:

```
/*css rule*/

#buttonMenuDiv > input{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

You can set display to inline or inline-block. But if you set them to inline, the 'width' and the 'height' attributes will not take effect any more.